# Query SQL Server database from MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linked-server

I am trying to find a work around to expedite our contractors work on our new website. The website is being created in WP using MySql, and some data that the website will dynamically load is located on our business SQL Server. Migration is out of the question.

Is there a way to query our SQL server from the MySql database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end result was that the workaround involved adding to an internal web app to populate the MySQL database with the data that we needed

Answer (score 0):

Querying SQL server from MySQL database is not the good solution I think. Why not querying the SQL server using PHP for example?

Comment: Because it seems that our contractors do not know what they are doing haha. Seriously though, they are having issues connecting to our SQL database, even though multiple tests have been done on connecting to the SQL database from outside our building.